# Changing color of comments in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

I am using Eclipse Indigo for my JSF project.

When I comment something, I want the color of the commented part should be gray (this is a default feature in Netbeans), how can I achieve?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can configure it at *Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring*.

[image]

Comment: What Eclipse Plugin is responsible for this?

Comment: @Imray: Just Eclipse for Java EE in its default trim. Giving the timestamp of the answer, I believe the screenshot is taken from Helios SR2. I checked it once again on my current Indigo SR2 and it's nearly exactly the same as on the screenshot.

Comment: I'd like to know what plugin is behind it so I can use the same coloring for my own view that I'm creating for my plugin

Comment: @Imray: Sorry, no idea. I don't develop Eclipse. I just develop *with* Eclipse :)