# Is there a way to use different colours for comments in eclipse (Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, colors, styles, comments

I want to use different colors for comments in eclipse (kepler). is there a way to do that? **I do not want to change the colour of all comments, but use at least two different colors for comments.**

Comment: Duplicate question. You can see this here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991224/changing-color-of-comments-in-eclipse)

Comment: @GAVD: no - this is not my question. I don't want to change the colour of all comments, but use different colours for different kinds of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is about using Eclipse's Java editor as a text processor, where areas of text can be marked and given different style - if that's the question then the clear answer is: this is not possible.

Syntax coloring in Eclipse only scans the existing text and associates different text styles to elements of different syntactic roles. Since there is no syntax for different colors inside comments, there is no way to distinguish different portions of a comment (with a few builtin exceptions like TODO tags, and tags within javadoc comments).

Answer (score 0):

[image]Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring.

In syntax coloring you can choose for multiline comments and single line comments. use it accordingly.

Comment: no - i highlighted the part of my question that makes things difficult

Comment: if you want two type of color then choose different for multi line and single line and use it. In pictures you can see blue and green line of comment. @floquet22